# rise compile-time error message with stream syntax

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

How to rise a compile-time error message where the error message is in a syntax like `std::cout`?

For example,

```
int main(void){
    int i = 14;
    int condition = 0;
    if (condition == 0){
        #error "no, " << i << " won't work.";
    }
}
```

Should give an error message like

```
"test.cpp:5: error: no, 14 won't work."
```

during compilation of the program, just like `#error` of g++ or `static_assert(false, "err_message");` of c++11.

In the above example, value of variable `i` "should" be known before actually running the program...

The actual place I need this is:

I have a multi-dimensional array with a static dimension. I want to rise a compiler time error that also mention the dimension (such as 3x4x5) of the multi-dimensional array.

I want a `std::cout` like stream syntax for the error message because cout can concatenate number and strings easily. I think `#error` can't concatenate number and strings.

would `constexpr` help?

Comment: You *want* to raise a compile-time error? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: This can only work for constants: Suppose `condition` would be `foo()` where `foo` is a function of some other compilation unit. Any compiler can never ever see the returned value of `foo` in order to determine whether to produce that warning.

Comment: There's no way you can do that. Preprocessing occurs even before compilation, so the variable doesn't exist yet..

Comment: Do you want a method with stream-like syntax, or do you actually want to use streams?  If it's the latter, I don't think it is possible, but if you want something that feels stream-like, you might be able to do it with a mixture of TMP and macros.

Comment: Can you explain more. Why doesn't `#error` work for you?

Comment: Simply not possible.  Preprocessor directives like `#error` are handled by the preprocessor, which executes and completes before the compilation phase where "stream syntax" is interpreted.   You're essentially asking for two distinct phases of compilation to be combined, in a way that is not supported at all in standard C++.

Comment: Use `std::array` (or even `std::vector`). Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition the compile time errors occur during compilation, either because the compiler doesn't understand something in your code, or because you specified conditions using preprocessor directive such as `#error` or static assertion `static_assert ( bool_constexpr , message )`.

Therefore, if you want to run check on your code, and write error messages using `cout`, you can no longer call results compile time errors because code used to check them was already compiled and errors themselves are thus run time errors.

Could you please write why doesn't #error do the trick for you?